# What is the Big-O for this block of code?

Tags: c++, performance, big-o

```
for( i = 1; i < n; ++i )
    for( j = 1; j < i * i; ++j )
        if( j % i == 0 )
            Boo();
```

Suppose Boo() is O(n^2), what would the total Big-O be for the above code block?

The outer for loop is O(n), the inner for loop is O(n^2), the if statement is O(n), so I'm expecting the total Big-O to be n * n^2 * n * n^2 = O(n^6).

But I'm not sure on whether I should include the Big-O of Boo() since it lies in the if statmement which only runs O(n) times.

Comment: Remember you can usually find out by running this for *N* at various powers of 10. By a million you quickly know what's going on.

Comment: *"the if statement is O(n)"* -- `if` statements are O(1) unless they call a function with a greater complexity. You might mean that the `if` condition evaluates to true (on the order of) `n` times, but then your claims are incomparable. You could compare the inner loop being O(n^2) with the `if` statement being O(1), **OR** you could compare the inner loop being O(n^3) (taking into account the outer loop) with the `if` statement being O(n) (taking into account the inner loop).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Time Complexity of Nested for Loops with if Statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58294341/) Also see [Time complexity of 3 nested loops with a condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69787557/) and [Time Complexity of Nested For Loop with If](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37982893/time-complexity-of-nested-for-loop-with-if)

Comment: I hate it when I start typing an answer and the question gets closed.

Comment: Based on [this](https://byjus.com/maths/sum-of-squares/).  Then number of iterations for any given value of `n` is:  `Σn2 = [n(n+1)(2n+1)]/6` - which is effectively **O(N³)**

Comment: The count is exactly `0.5*N^2`  https://godbolt.org/z/Wv7ThP1E7